# How do I resolve an "unused argument error" in R? What does this error mean?

Tags: r

When trying to generate 200 randomly generated numbers from a normal distribution, I receive an error saying there are unused arguments. Although, I am sure I wrote the same piece of code below and it generated 200 numbers before. The code I am trying to write can be seen below, along with the error I have received:

```
    weight_before <- rnorm(n = 200, mean = 20, var = 2)
    weight_after <- rnorm(n = 200, mean = 21, var = 2.5)
```

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I have carried out some research on the internet and the rstudio community to try and identify the reason why I get this error and how to resolve it, but I have been unable to find an answer. Can someone also tell me what is the purpose of this error message?

Comment: The argument name is `sd`, not `var`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you were using *compositions* package by accident, this package has the argument var in their sampling functions.

https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/compositions/versions/2.0-1/topics/rnorm

I get the same error as you when using:

```
weight_before <- rnorm(n = 200, mean = 20, var = 2)
weight_after <- rnorm(n = 200, mean = 21, var = 2.5)
```

Note that rnorm is from *stats* R builtin package.

Answer (score 0):

Please always consider using the `R` built in help function. You can access it by adding a `?` before a function name and then running the line.

Running `?rnorm` gives you the hint that `sd` is  used for standard deviation rather than your `var`.

Comment: I have used ?rnorm, and I understand that sd is used for standard deviation; but I am trying to specify the variance, not the standard deviation.

Comment: The `rnorm()` function does not accept the variance, but if you know that variance is the square of the standard deviation, you can can use `rnorm(n = 200, mean = 20, sd = sqrt(2))`

Comment: I will try that.